# How to convert a basic data partition back to a bootable partition

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have two SSD's in my PC both running Windows 10 pro.
One of the drives needed to be reset - did so using the `Windows10Upgrade9252.exe` I downloaded from Microsoft.

It went well but for some reason after the upgrade was finished my second drive was converted to a (Basic Data Partition) and can't be booted from anymore.

I have no idea why this happened. I can't seem to find a way to convert it back to a bootable partition. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What was the drive before this happened if not Basic? Unclear: I can see that Disk 1 is bootable.

Comment: Seems like the partition table of `Disc 0` has been converted from MBR-style to GPT-style. I suppose you could either convert it back by some means (and make sure the boot code on the MBR is there again, by using `bootsect.exe`) and continue UEFI+legacy dual booting. Or you could make the installation on `Disc 0` "share" the EFI system partition on `Disc 1` by using `bcdedit.exe` (dual boot with Windows Boot Manager instead of the UEFI boot menu, that is).

Comment: You can also shrink the main partition on `Disc 0` for a bit and create a ESP dedicated to the installation on it and install another set of WBM with `bcdboot`.

Comment: harrymc thanks for the reply, The drive use to be my primary C: but if I booted from the second drive it would become d: and visa versa.                                                                                                                              As for MBR they are both GUID Partition Table (GTP) drives and have always been so. And that makes it even more baffling.

Answer (score 0):

Solved..
I was able to successfully update the NTFS file system bootcode and now both drives are bootable again.

Bootsect /nt60 all /force

In the video he cleaned the disc using diskpart but I was able to do it without wiping everything out here's the link.

https://youtu.be/F72D7uL6cZg